# Is it possible to salvage my really poorly received Java 8 question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I asked [a Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46788291) a few days ago, and it was received really terribly, with 3 delete, 5 close, and 8 down votes, in one and a half hour.

The discussion generated several interesting comments on the topic, but with respect to the closing/deleting of the question, the only feedback  was that

> You should really learn how to work efficiently with Java 8 before you start complaining

and

> Comparing two unrelated languages to each other and wondering why one is different from another is not a very good question

which don't really give insight into how the post could be improved.

I am interested in salvaging this question though, because it isn't fully answered, since [Holger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788291/why-are-java-streams-so-verbose#comment80523230_46788291) modifies the initial list, so it isn't equivalent to the examples in the question.

Does the meta community have any ideas how to improve the question? How could it be edited to become less "opinion based"?

Comment: I feel like the less opinion based version of your question is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274232/java-8-streams-and-maps-worth-it)

Comment: @Keiwan: The question you linked looks really good, I will study it

Comment: The comment *"You should really learn how to work efficiently with Java 8 before you start complaining. Java is not Ruby, so don't try to write it as if it were"* seems a bit cheeky to be honest.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, I was put off a bit too when I saw it, but the commenter did vote to repoen the question after it was edited, and [posted a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788291/how-to-call-a-lambda-on-each-element-of-a-list-and-get-the-result-in-a-new-list#comment80943536_46788291) in the comments, so his overall participation on the question was constructive in my view.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Comparing two unrelated languages to each other and wondering why one is different from another is not a very good question.

I would agree with this comment, and suggest it as the primary reason that your question was poorly received. You don't really seem to have a focused and constructive point of inquiry. The way that you've written the question is inviting a discussion, not a solution.

You ask:

> Couldn't the language be written to avoid the conversion of Lists to Streams and vice versa, and apply the map function directly like in Ruby?

I mean...sure? If you wanted to rewrite the entire language, I guess. Anything's possible.

Let me ask you this: what does a satisfactory answer to your question *look like*? What packet of information would make you smile, nod, and award that green checkmark with pleasure? I suspect that, starting from any given answer that another human is likely to produce, there would be a lot of back-and-forth to get you to that point.

And that's...not really how we like to do things here.

So, as far as salvaging, I suggest taking another small step back. Imagine that your question was answered perfectly: how would that change what you do going forward? What effect do you hope to achieve with the information you get?

It may be that you're just asking the question out of "curiosity". You're truly, fundamentally wondering about the language design, and why this one is so succinct and the other one is so wordy. If so -- and I hate to say it -- it may be that Stack Overflow simply isn't the right place.

If not, though, there's something you want *to do*. There's a specific, concrete goal that you have for your work. And if that's true, then reword your question to **ask about that**.

This is similar to what's been called [an Atwood's transform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124930/159251): you have a specific thing you want to do, and your brain [runs down all sorts of possibilities](https://xkcd.com/1908/), and you start wondering about them as if they're an end in themselves, and then you ask this really general question where nobody has any idea what you're trying to do, because you yourself have lost sight of your goal.

In short,* edit and refocus your question on what you actually hope to achieve, instead of the broader context, and I think you'll have a solid Stack Overflow post.

---

*[Too late!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCP2QQH4uuQ)

Comment: You raise some valid points. Regarding the concrete problem to be solved, it would be this: "How to call a lambda on each element of a list and get the result in a new list? My working version is too verbose". That's why I mentioned Holger's comment, it would be the perfect answer if instead of modifying the existing list, it returned a new one.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that sounds like a perfectly fine question for SO.

Comment: Well I made an edit on the question, let's see how it goes...

Comment: The question is now undeleted and re-opened, so I am accepting this answer as correct. Thank you very much for your feedback, it was really helpful.

Answer (score -45):

I think that people who complain about being asked a bad question should really take a long hard look at themselves, because very often the people who have a poorly worded and knee jerk "This is a bad question!" reaction are precisely the sort of people who just realized that they didn't know the field the question was posed in as well as they previously thought, and instead of taking it out on themselves, they take it out on the novice who asked a good question that they don't have an answer for, and try to shout him down to pretend like none of this ever happened.

Comparing two programming languages is a valid criticism of one language over another. Unless you want me to believe that all languages are equally perfect and are all perfect, you want to make these sorts of comparisons, and gradually give a language a bad reputation (like the one Javascript suffers from) so it can be phased out, or a new language created which is better than either.

Oh and people complaining about something being opinion based are idiots. Something is either wrong, or right. Calling something opinion based is frankly irrelevant.

Comment: You're free to debate this post in comments - but you must do so in a civil and constructive manner. There's no need for flinging accusations and insults about.

Comment: Yes there was, there very clearly was Jon. This site is filled to the brim with arm chair experts who, when confronted with a real question, blame the person asking the question on some technicality or other (usually wrongly), either to buy time, or to punish the person asking the question for revealing the responder's ignorance.

Comment: Well, we can't disregard the asking rules, they were set in place for good reason. If no restrictions were in place the site would be flooded with trivially searchable and no-effort debugging questions, to the point that the challenging problems would stay unanswered... Having said that, I find it really unfair that [people are downvoting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LMa4.png) unrelated posts of Isaac59001010 on a different site, just because they disagree with something he said on meta. The fact they limit themselves to two downvotes each to avoid the reversal script is even more disturbing.

Comment: @user000001 Considering the questions you are linking, I think it is entirely possible the down-votes are legitimate. One of those appears to have been deleted, and to be a duplicate to the one that isn't? That's neither here nor there, but since you brought it up...

Comment: _"Comparing two programming languages is a valid criticism of one language over another."_ Yes, but that doesn't make for an answerable question, suitable on a Question and Answer site.

Comment: @Isaac59001010 These so-called "arm chair experts" didn't criticize the question because they thought it was unanswerable; they criticized it because they thought it wasn't a good fit here, and they were right. You'll notice that after the question's been edited, it's now a well-received question. Did those "arm chair experts" suddenly learn Java/Ruby? Your stance is a little ironic; you've joined a new site and promptly accused its community of feigning understanding where you're quite frankly wrong. Seems like only one person here is sitting in an arm chair...